# I'm getting [Errno 13] Permission denied after adding some git submodules to the project (in qooxdoo)

Tags: git, permissions, qooxdoo

The error happens when I try to compile my qooxdoo application:

```
 generate.py source

 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Executing: source::source-script
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 >>> Scanning libraries  [Errno 13] Permission denied:      
 u'C:\\web\\production01_server\\node_modules\\production\\client\\Qooxdoo'
```

I recently added qooxdoo as a sub-module to use that qooxdoo folder to generate. It didn't work because of this error. Now I've put back to the last qooxdoo path and the error is the same.

Worked previously:

```
        {
           "manifest" : "../../../../../about_projects/third_party/qooxdoo/qooxdoo-1.6-sdk"
          ,"uri": "/qooxdoo"
        }
```

And now it is not working. I've changed the path in the config.json.

Now I don't even know what the problem is:

- I've added permission/ownership to all the files for my user
- I've removed all the read-only files

And the problem still exists.

I'm using win-vista.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I should be changed:

```
        "QOOXDOO_PATH" : "../Qooxdoo",
```

instead of library.

Even so I still have an error that seems [more solvable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605206/qooxdoo-as-git-submodule-expecting-property-name-in-component-testrunner-testru):

```
>>> Processing configuration
Expecting property name: line 626 column 3 (char 13185)
File:
C:\web\production01_server\node_modules\production\client\Qooxdoo\component\testrunner\testrunner.json
```

Happened again, it seems that if I left qooxdoo in the libraries like this:

```
        {
           "manifest" : "../Qooxdoo"
          ,"uri": "/qooxdoo"
        }
```

throws the error in this question.